# VBA read union range horizontally

Tags: vba, excel, range, union

I'm trying to combine the values in a range of cells. I created a range as follows:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Application.Union(Range("A1:A3"), Range("C1:E2"))
For Each Address In rng
Debug.Print Address.Address
Next
```

I want to read the cells in horizontal order: A1,C1,D1,E1,A2,C2... etc.
But instead they're being read A1,A2,A3,C1,C2,.. etc

How can I read them horizontally?
Thanks

Comment: Tangent but why would you set a variable to a syntax word immediately following it XD Edit: so change your for loop to use row and column.

Comment: Do *not* use `Address` as a variable type, as that's a special "word" in VBA.  Instead do like, `myAddress` or `Adrs` or something.

Comment: Point taken RE Address. But what's this loop to use row and column you mention?

Comment: If you want it to loop a certain way, code it to loop it exactly that way. Lot more work but if you want it that badly... Edit: you know, with r=1 c=1 then r=r+1 etc

Answer (score 5):

You have to deal with the [Range.Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196243.aspx) within the [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) created with the [Union method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx).

```
Sub laterally()
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, a As Long
    Dim mnRW As Long, mxRW As Long, mnCL As Long, mxCL As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")   '<~~ ALWAYS set the worksheet!
        Set rng = Union(.Range("A1:A3"), .Range("C1:E2"))
        Debug.Print rng.Address(0, 0)
        mnRW = Rows.Count: mxRW = 0
        mnCL = Columns.Count: mxCL = 0
        With rng
            For a = 1 To .Areas.Count
                With .Areas(a)
                    mnRW = Application.Min(mnRW, .Rows(1).Row)
                    mxRW = Application.Max(mxRW, .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row)
                    mnCL = Application.Min(mnCL, .Columns(1).Column)
                    mxCL = Application.Max(mxCL, .Columns(.Columns.Count).Column)
                End With
            Next a
            For r = mnRW To mxRW
                For c = mnCL To mxCL
                    If Not Intersect(.Cells, .Parent.Cells(r, c)) Is Nothing Then _
                        Debug.Print .Parent.Cells(r, c).Address(0, 0)
                Next c
            Next r
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

After collecting the extents of the unioned range, each possible cell is looped through and the [Intersect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772(v=office.11).aspx) is used to determine whether it belongs in the union or not.

Answer (score 3):

A union of ranges doesn't care in which order the cells are added - whether it's by row or by column. So your original loop to unify the ranges is fine.

If you're concerned about the order in which you read the data, simply read by row or by column accordingly, with an inner and an outer loop. So for example, after you build the range, do as follows:

```
Dim Col as Variant, Rw as Variant
For Each Col in rng.Columns
    For each Rw in Col.Rows
        Debug.Print Rw.Address
    Next Rw
Next Col
```

Comment: Oooo much smarter than my idea^^

Comment: I'm unclear on how this answers the primary (to my mind) point of the original question; to wit: How do I loop through A1, C1, D1, E1, A2, C2, D2, E2, A3?

Comment: @Chris I'm trying to use your solution to go by row, but I can't seem to get it to print out correctly.  Is it working on your side?

Comment: `For each Rw in Col.Rows` typo I think XD Why doesn't this work @Jeeped? Edit: oh duh. Wrong way. Row first then column XD

Comment: Ahh.. so sorry. Of course, the original range union was not contiguous, in that it covers more than one area. My solution is a quick & easy one for a contiguous range area. I should have paid more attention to the actual addresses being set up! My solutions works in that it reads horizontally _per area_ - however in the meantime Jeeped below has a solution which handles multiple areas.

Comment: @findwindow - The OP's union was **1** range but **2** areas.

Comment: @Jeeped right. So it would stop at edge of one area?? That seems wrong given that loop is for range....?

Comment: @findwindow - Currently the above code is only returning the `Rw.Address`. Wait for any correction made.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Whilst Jeeped might have the correct answer, I found it to be over complicated for my skill set. I ended up dumbing it down with 2 lines of code:    If Not myAddress.Column = 4 And Not myAddress.Column = 5

Answer (score 0):

Just thought this might be an interesting addition to Chris' solution?
(I changed the range slightly to highlight some of the advantages)

```
Dim Rng As Range, Col As Variant, Rw As Variant

Set Rng = Application.Union(Range("A3:A5"), Range("C2:E4"))
For Each Rw In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
    For Each Col In Rw.Columns
        If Not Intersect(Col, Rng) Is Nothing Then Debug.Print Intersect(Col, Rng).Address
    Next Col
Next Rw
```